# Android: fragments to overlap other elements

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want achieve the following visual appearance in my application as shown below, so the rounded image is overlaps the map and its parent panel.

[image]

But the result is quite far from it

[image]

### Main fragment code

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$WalkFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/talk_panel"
        android:name="com.app.fragments.TalkFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Bottom panel source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/talk_panel_inner"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/talk_background"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:clickable="true">

    <!-- THIS IS ELEMENT SHOULD OVERLAP ITS PARENTS -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-26dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_slide"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up_grey"
            android:clickable="true"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp">

            <EditText
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/search_box"
                android:fontFamily="Roboto"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_icon"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:hint="@string/search_places"
                android:background="@drawable/text_area"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_clear"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/place_color"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@string/loading_place_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I've tried with `RelativeLayout, LinearLayout`, tried to wrap fragment `talk_panel` with `LinearLayout` etc. but it didn't work out.

Can anyone help me with it? Any ideas and suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, may be it will be useful for people. So I wrapped my fragment and rounded image into a `RelativeLayout` and applied circle shape to my `ImageView`, set positions as well.

### Result

[image]

### Footer fragment

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/talk_panel"
        android:name="com.app.fragments.TalkFragment"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/talk_panel"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### @drawable/circle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>

    <size
        android:width="160dp"
        android:height="160dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a frame layout on top of both fragments, then align the image within the frame.  At runtime, either add the image view to the frame, or set it's top and left layout margin using it's `LayoutParams` (of type `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`), then `requestLayout()`.

For aligning the image correctly, call `getBottom()` or `getTop()` on the fragment layouts, then pass that value (plus or minus half the image's height, to center it) into the marginTop.